# JSON.NET writing invalid JSON?

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization, windows-phone-7, json.net

It appears that JSON.NET is writing invalid JSON, although I wouldn't be surprised if it was due to my misuse.

It appears that it is repeating the last few characters of JSON:

```
/* ... */ "Teaser":"\nfoo.\n","Title":"bar","ImageSrc":null,"Nid":44462,"Vid":17}]}4462,"Vid":17}]}
```

The repeating string is:

```
4462,"Vid":17}]}
```

I printed it out to the console, so I don't think this is a bug in Visual Studio's text visualizer.

The serialization code:

```
       static IDictionary<int, ObservableCollection<Story>> _sectionStories;
       private static void writeToFile()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(STORIES_FILE, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_sectionStories));
                }

            }

#if DEBUG
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(storage.OpenFile(STORIES_FILE, FileMode.Open));
            string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

            JObject data = JObject.Parse(contents);
            string result = "";
            foreach (char c in contents.Skip(contents.Length - 20))
            {
                result += c;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(result);

            // crashes here with ArgumentException
            // perhaps because JSON is invalid?
            var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, List<Story>>>(contents);
#endif
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a bug? Are there any known workarounds?

Curiously, `JObject.Parse()` doesn't throw any errors.

I'm building a Silverlight app for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: It is not clear which ones you mean it is repeating and what the underlying structure is.

Comment: Are you sure that is not part of the object??? How is it possible to have a repeating element and the text is deserializable? I cannot believe it. Put the whole JSON if you can.

Comment: X-Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092985/datacontractserializer-problem-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 3):

When writing the file you specify

```
FileMode.OpenOrCreate
```

If the file exists and is 16 bytes longer than the data you intend to write to it (from an older version of your data that just happens to end with the exact same data) then that data will still be present when you're done writing your new data.

Solution:

```
FileMode.Create
```

From:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

FileMode.Create: Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten